# jsPDF creates pdf with several blanck pages after content

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF in my reactjs project to download a pdf with some html content. It renders fine the html component but after it it renders multiple empty pages, so I end up getting a 7 page pdf instead of a 1 page pdf when the html only covers a part of the first page.

This is the logic I use.

```
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

export const pdf = ({ 
    filename
}) => {
    const doc = new jsPDF({orientation:'p', unit :'pt', format: 'a2', precision: 1});

    doc.html(document.getElementById("presupuesto"), {
        callback: function (doc) {
            doc.save(filename);
        },
        x: 10,
        y: 10,
        windowWidth:100
     }); 
}
```

And this is the html that gets rendered.

```
<div id="presupuesto" style={{width: "109.5%"}}>
        <div style={{
            backgroundColor: "black",
            padding: "15px",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between"
        }}>
            <img src={Logo} alt="Logo" />
            <h3 style={{ fontWeight: "800"}}>FACTURA</h3>
        </div>
        <div style={{
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "space-between",
            padding: "10px"
        }}>
            <div>
                <h5>Punto de venta</h5>
                <p style={{margin: 0}}>Sucursal  {generalData.deposito}</p>
                <p style={{margin: 0}}>Vendedor : {generalData.vendedor}</p>  
            </div>
            <div>
            <h5>Facturar a</h5>
            <p style={{margin: 0}}>{header.cliente.razonSocial}</p>
            <p style={{margin: 0}}>{header.cliente.domicilio}</p>
            <p style={{margin: 0}}>{header.cliente.email}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <p style={{margin: 0}}>Fecha : {generalData.today}</p>
                <p style={{margin: 0}}>Factura  "{header.typoFactura}"" - {header.numFactura}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <Table responsive striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Cantidad</th>
            <th style={{ width: "60%"}}>Descripción</th>
            <th>Subtotal efectivo</th>
            <th>Total efectivo</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {productos.map((p, index) => {
            const number = Number(p.precioVenta)
            const cantidad = Number(p.cantidad);
            const result = Number(number*cantidad);
            
            return (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center"}}>
                <input style={{width: "70px", margin: "0 10px"}} className="form-control" type="number" value={p.cantidad} disabled={true} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <div style={{
                      display: "flex",
                      alignItems: "center",
                      justifyContent: "space-between"
                }}>
                  {p.descripcion} 
                </div>
              </td>
              <td>
                 <CurrencyFormat value={number} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <CurrencyFormat value={result} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
              </td>
              <td></td>
            </tr>
          )})}
          {productos.length !== 0 && (
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Sub total</td>
            <td><CurrencyFormat value={total} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} /></td>
          </tr>
          )}
        </tbody>
        </Table>
        <Table responsive striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Importe Neto Gravado</th>
            <th>IVA 21%</th>
            <th>Total de la operación</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <CurrencyFormat value={totalOperation - iva} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <CurrencyFormat value={iva} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
              </td>
              <td>
                <CurrencyFormat value={totalOperation} displayType={'text'} thousandSeparator={true} prefix={'$'} />
              </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
```

That content covers barely half of a page, but I still get aproximately 7 pages. What should I do?

Comment: Can you try setting the format to something smaller than a2? perhaps a4

Comment: I use a2 because it's the only way to fit the width of my html inside the page, however I tried with a4 and I get 13 pages where the first one is my component cut in half because it doesn't fit